# javascript searching with condition

Tags: javascript

I am searching a list of string in a specific long string.

Imagine the long stream is :`Jim participates in a free wrestling competition`

and the array is :`["Jim","free","not","me","you","wrestling"]`

the problem is that i want just the names to be retrieved not the other part.

in the up example i need just "Jim" and not "free" or "wrestling".

by the way, the name can be in any position of array.

this is my code.

```js
    title = document.getElementById("title").value
    cat_list = document.getElementById("category-all").textContent.replace(/\n\n/g, "\n").replace(/^\s*/g, "").trim().split("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < cat_list.length; i++){
        if(title.indexOf(cat_list[i]) > -1){
            return cat_list[i]
        }
    }
```

how can i insert this condition to my code?

Comment: what does `'Jim'` qualifiy? just because it's the first in the array?

Comment: How can you determine, that the index that your'e looking for is the name and not anything else ?

Comment: the name is not at the first of sentence all the time.
and about your second question , this is my question also
how to determine names

Comment: Is "Grasoentuhaou" a name? How can you tell? You need to define what a "name" is, first.

Comment: right, but **how** do you determine names in sense of programming?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the thing you call **name** is just a `string` and you seek the **intersection**:

```
var str = "Jim participates in a free wrestling competition"

var arr1 = ["Jim","free","not","me","you","wrestling"]
var arr2 = str.split(" ")

array1.filter((n) => array2.includes(n))
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) for more.

If you are looking for special names (like person names) there is no way other than checking if it is title case; but any name being the first word of the sentence is title case. So, it breaks your case.

Comment: OP said it shouldn't match "free" or "wrestling", so I'm not sure this is the solution.

Comment: Well, first part of the answer is an assumption; and that is what I also mean on the second part. And yes, there is no feasible solution for this question indeed -apart from keeping and maintaining a name file/array etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the element you want in the array and then get it like this in ES6:

```
const cat_list = ["Jim","free","not","me","you","wrestling"];
let nameIndex = cat_list.findIndex(x => x.toString().trim().toUpper() === 'JIM'); 
//instead of hardcoding try to find a way to generalize it like cat_list[name] or something
const name = cat_list[nameIndex];
```